# Sencha Touch 2 - Panel stops working after build

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have some trouble using an Ext.Panel in Sencha Touch 2.2. It works at first, but after building it can't be closed though hideOnMaskTap is true.

Here's my code:

**MinPanel.js**

```
Ext.define('MinimalPanelExample.view.MinPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.dataview.List'
    ],

    config: {
        id: 'minPanel',
        width: '320px',
        height: '480px',
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: true,

        html: 'minimal panel',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Adding it in **Main.js**:

```
var minPanel = Ext.create('MinimalPanelExample.view.MinPanel');

[...]
items: {
    docked: 'top',
    xtype: 'titlebar',
    title: 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Button',
            listeners: {
                tap: function(button) {
                    minPanel.showBy(button);
                }
            }
        }
    ],
},
```

What's curious is that the list inside the panel isn't even shown if I run the built package, it just shows the html: 'minimal panel'. There's no warnings in the Javascript console, though.

Any ideas about why that happens?
Also, feel free to tell me if my way of creating / accessing the panel in the first place is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You can't just Ext.create on top of the Main view file, it has to be somewhere in the Ext.define block. It works if I create the MinPanel in an initialize listener, and then get it via Ext.getCmp('minPanel') when the user presses the button.